# error Failed to run jetifier. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details

Tags: android, gradle, androidx, android-jetifier

Initially I created projects that were running normally
with react-native run-android, now it has the following error:
Já tentei o comando: react-native run-android --no-jetifier

Detail the code that I circled, it no longer works for any project you try to create.

```
 PS C:\Users\Morgana Ribeiro\curso-react-native\nubank> react-native run-android`
    info Running jetifier to migrate libraries to AndroidX. You can disable it using "--no-jetifier" flag.
    error Failed to run jetifier. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.    
Error: spawnSync C:\Users\Morgana Ribeiro\curso-react-native\nubank\node_modules\jetifier\bin\jetify ENOENT
        at Object.spawnSync (internal/child_process.js:1002:20)
        at spawnSync (child_process.js:614:24)
        at execFileSync (child_process.js:642:13)
        at Object.runAndroid [as func] (C:\Users\Morgana Ribeiro\curso-react-native\nubank\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\index.js:101:41)
        at Command.handleAction (C:\Users\Morgana Ribeiro\curso-react-native\nubank\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\cliEntry.js:160:21)
        at Command.listener (C:\Users\Morgana Ribeiro\curso-react-native\nubank\node_modules\commander\index.js:315:8)
        at Command.emit (events.js:198:13)
        at Command.parseArgs (C:\Users\Morgana Ribeiro\curso-react-native\nubank\node_modules\commander\index.js:651:12)
        at Command.parse (C:\Users\Morgana Ribeiro\curso-react-native\nubank\node_modules\commander\index.js:474:21)
at setupAndRun (C:\Users\Morgana Ribeiro\curso-react-native\nubank\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\cliEntry.js:210:24)
```

Comment: English please!